# How to get over 75% in an exam/coursework at masters level?

Tags: united-kingdom, exams, assessment

I'm half way through my MBA, and my highest mark is around 73%, which I've had in several modules and pieces of coursework. I've contacted the university to ask for concrete examples of previous answers for exams I've sat that have received > 80% but they won't provide any. I've read several books on critical thinking and essay writing, but still something's missing.

The university has published guidelines for > 80%, and they're things like:

> Exploration of topic showing excellent knowledge & understanding through thorough & appropriate research. Impressive choice and range of appropriate content.

and other similar vague statements.

Specifically, how can I get over > 80% for an exam/coursework at masters level, or should I take this further with the university?

Comment: You did not specify the country here. In some countries, 70+% is considered to be a very good grade. While in some, it is a bad one. Also, sometimes, it is hard to get 80%+.

Comment: This is in the UK. 70+ is a first, but I need to make up my grade average since I'm currently averaging high 60s.

Comment: It looks like I'm being downvoted, probably by my university :D

Comment: Your post is somewhat off-topic I guess

Comment: There may literally be no recent examples of scores above 80.  Scoring above 80 tends to require doing better than the instructors think they could have done themselves.

Comment: RE the downvotes: this question is essentially "how to get better grades," and that's not something we can help with; it too broad and the answers depend on each individual. Some other sites do invite discussion or brainstorming, but we are strictly Q&A. Moreover, you seem to have concerns about how you personally are being marked, so you really need to be talking to instructors or graders who are familiar with your work and the course standards. If the question were "is it true that scores > 80% are effectively unachievable in the UK", that might be something we could help with.

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/191600/is-it-true-that-scores-80-are-effectively-unachievable-in-the-uk

Comment: @jbrown It doesn't seem like the system is designed for you to obtain a "first" through a mixture of grades in the low 60s and below and those far above 70, rather if you want an average above 70 you should aim to have all your grades above 70. See also [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) about asking about your actual problem rather than your proposed solution.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is somewhat subject-dependent.

In more precise disciplines such as Mathematics for example,  exam problems normally have exact answers. For such disciplines, it is sufficient to correctly solve all problems to score 100% of the exam mark. Whether a mathematical problem is solved correctly can be objectively established by checking all the arguments, which reduces the scope for bias and ambiguity in marking.

Many disciplines are not as precise as Mathematics. Studying for such degrees involves reading a lot of approaches to the same question, which sometimes contradict each other. By reading and critically discussing those approaches students learn to be creative and apply appropriate decisions in difficult situations. Normally, a problem is open-ended, does not have a unique exact solution, and students are expected to explain and justify their approaches but sometimes also critique them and discuss their weaknesses. Normally assessment of such modules is based on coursework rather than exam. For coursework, students are expected to produce an essay with broad discussion of a topic. Obviously, marking of such work is subjective to a certain degree. University guidelines are vague because they are applicable to all disciplines. Your lecturers are experts in their own area and are able to contextualise what exactly they expect from an essay to give it a mark of 80%. They may not want to share examples with students, because it often leads to work being copied and students arguing that their piece is "the same" as the example that scored 80%. This of course defeats the purpose of the assignment.

Comment: Thanks, you make some good points. However, I'm trying to get examples from my university for modules I've already completed to avoid the latter points. As of now unfortunately I have been unable to get hold of a single example of what's required to get > 80%. Since exams aren't about original research I'm stumped by what might count as this "excellent knowledge" and originality of thought they seem to be looking for.

Comment: As far as exams are concerned, some (most?) Maths Depts in the UK publish model (=correct) solutions for all students after the exam grades are out by default. If your Dept is not doing it, it may be because they want to reuse exams and save themselves a trouble of writing a new exam each year. Or maybe customs in MBA Depts are different, I dunno. You may engage with your student union to see if you can collectively argue to make it happen.

Comment: I think a better analogue for project work in an MBA is project work in mathematics where there are no "exact answers".

Comment: @erstwhileeditor I agree, but project work is a very broadly defined activity which can be assessed in many different ways. For example a project on "building a bridge" has a clearly objective measure of quality (weight the bridge can sustain). A project on "Fibonacci numbers in modern society" can be very discussion-oriented and much closer to an essay with subjective criteria for assessment.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean when you say you have contacted "the university" --- it's an awfully big institution with many people in it.  In any case, if you would like to know the shortcomings of your work and how you can improve it, you should seek feedback on your work from your course lecturer.  Given your specific interest, you might wish to ask your lecturer what more they would want to see in the work to get it to the point of being at the high grade level you have mentioned.

As to getting examples of work at high grade level, that might be possible, but it can also be tricky.  Lecturers typically treat student assessment as confidential and do not circulate it to other students.  If a lecturer has taught a course for several years then they might be able to anonymise a past submission for this purpose, or even seek permission from the student to waive confidentiality to allow circulation of their work (as an example of a high-quality submission).  I recommend that you let your lecturer know that it would be helpful to have examples of this kind and see what can be done.

Aside from talking with your lecturer to get feedback and examples of good work, no, you should not take this further with the university.

Comment: Re not taking it further. Why do you think that? I feel like I'm expected to take assessments but no one can tell me what's expected beyond bascially "do a good job". Since my course and my time is expensive I don't think this is good enough.